# MongoServerError: WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I see a lot of following errors in my logs when I try to update only 2 documents with the transaction:

```
MongoServerError: WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.
```

From all the docs I read, this can be an issue when modifying more than 1000 documents, but since I am updating only 2, it should not throw any error.

I want to mention that the error only happens sometimes randomly. Usually, the logic will pass without the error.

**MongoDB version:** 5.0.14

Here is the code:

```js
exports.setArticleView = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.user._id;
  const { article_id } = req.body;

  // Start a session
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();

  try {
    // Start a transaction
    session.startTransaction();

    await ArticleView.create([{ articleId: article_id, user: userId }], { session });

    await Article.updateOne({ _id: article_id }, { $inc: { views: 1 } }, { session });

    // Commit the transaction
    await session.commitTransaction();

    return res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false });
  } finally {
    // End session
    session.endSession();
  }
};
```

I think it’s the following scenario when the error happens:

1. One user view the article and transaction starts for that user.
2. Second user view the article after a few milliseconds (almost the same time) after the first user.
3. Since transaction of the first user didn’t finish, the transaction for the second user aborts.

I assume this based on the following paragraph from the docs:

> If a multi-document transaction is in progress, new DDL operations that affect the same database(s) or collection(s) wait behind the transaction. While these pending DDL operations exist, new transactions that access the same database(s) or collection(s) as the pending DDL operations cannot obtain the required locks and and will abort after waiting  [`maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/parameters/#mongodb-parameter-param.maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis) (which defaults to 5ms).

I think it can probably be solved by increasing the `maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis` , but I wanted to check with the community. If I would increase `maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis` config, would that have some further implications?

Comment: I believe this behavior is outlined [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions-production-consideration/) (which I arrived at from [this discussion on the forums](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/recommended-way-to-handle-write-conflicts-inside-transactions/104491) that surfaced when I searched). I don't think the number of documents is particularly relevant to the behavior apart from potentially making occurrence of the behavior more likely in some ways?

Answer (score 0):

This would happen whenever multiple users view the same article at the same time (e.g., two transactions are in flight at the same time).

You can probably reproduce this trivially by adding an arbitrary sleep between  `session.startTransaction()` and `session.commitTransaction();`, then viewing the same article in two windows (or otherwise triggering that behaviour twice)

You have a few options here:

1. personally - I'd probably not use a transaction at all, the transaction is only going to help you if your app server goes down in between the two operations, if it isn't mission critical that those numbers always exactly match, I'd remove the transaction entirely and maybe just once per day re-compute the `views` from the `ArticleView` collection count.
2. retry the operation as the error suggests - in your catch, you can detect the `WriteConflict` error and retry the entire function (probably with a small backoff)
3. (a variant of 1) if your collections are indexed and not particularly large, you could remove the transaction and change your `$inc` to a `$set` and pull the count in that way